# SVG image scale from center with slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, snap.svg

I made a Jquery ui slider to dynamically control the size of SVG image in the mask. The image gets resized from left-top corner. I'm wondering to know that is that possible to resize the image from center? Any idea would be appreciated.

https://jsfiddle.net/david7418/o497akje/

```
  obj = Snap(".cat");
  obj.drag();
  var dimens = obj.node.getBoundingClientRect();
  $("#slider").slider({
      max: dimens.width,
      min: dimens.width / 5,
      step: 1,
      value: dimens.width,
      slide: function(event, ui) {
          obj.attr({
              width: ui.value
          });
      }
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

You also need to move the image's `x` and `y` and `height` as you adjust the `width`.

I also changed the slider to return a percentage. I think it's a little more obvious what's going on that way.

```
$(function() {
   obj = Snap(".cat");
   var dimens = obj.node.getBoundingClientRect();     
   console.log(dimens.width)
   $( "#slider" ).slider({
      max: 100, 
      min: 100/5, 
      step:1, 
      value:dimens.width,
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
         w = ui.value * dimens.width / 100;
         h = ui.value * dimens.height / 100;
         obj.attr({
            width: w,
            height: h,
            x: (dimens.width - w)/2,
            y: (dimens.height - h)/2
         });
      }
   });
});
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o497akje/2/)

Comment: Perfect!! This is exactly what I want. Thank you bro. I modified your code to let the resize behavior makes more sense. https://jsfiddle.net/david7418/o497akje/5/ 
Please allow me to ask me one more question about this. I just added dragging event to allow image moving by mouse. Is that possible to limit moving range to keep image display full star mask?

Comment: Well, I've finished whole things includes resizing, rotating and dragging(except dragging range limitation). Here is the demo in case someone needs it. https://jsfiddle.net/david7418/o497akje/6/

Comment: But, there is a little issue. If I rotate image after moving, the image always goes back to the center of the mask. I think that is something wrong on matrix calculation. Any idea?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. It seems to be bahaving as expected for me (checked Chrome and FF)

Comment: Please drag the image to anywhere you like, and then rotate it. The image will go back to the original place(center of the mask). It's supposed to be rotated at the location that you dropped.

Comment: `obj.drag()` is modifying the image's `transform`. You are overwriting that when you do `obj.transform('r'+ui.value)`. You need change that so you are updating the transform instead of overwriting it.

Comment: Thanks for the replay. Yeah, I'm not familiar with transform and still figuring out how to deal with it.

Answer (score -1):

With SVG the default position for transforms to start is the top left corner. So, in order to override this, you need to explicitly set a transform-origin on the SVG like this:

```
svg {
    transform-origin: center center;
}
```

Comment: I think it only works on normal image in html tag. It doesn't work for svg image at less in mask.

Comment: Ah. I see. You're scaling the image, not the SVG. Sorry, my mistake. I read the question wrong it seems. :)